# What is the correct traffic pattern for this intersection?

Tags: traffic, british-columbia, accident

The intersections in question is where Government St splits off from Douglas St. (Victoria, BC, Canada)
I have to use this intersection every day on my way to work and have witnessed several near-misses when drivers take unexpected actions.
I have built a diagram (below) of what seems to be the most popular doctrine regarding the intersection:
[image: Intersection Diagram]

Comment: There are 4 lanes. The right lane (1) is a bus lane. The left lane (4) is marked 'turn left'. So If you are swerving from lane (3), the unmarked 'straight ahead' lane, across traffic on lane (2), which is not marked 'turn right', to the Government St exit you do not have right of way. (Note: looked on Google Street View).

Comment: @WeatherVane, So you're suggesting the second option is correct, except only busses should be using the right-most lane to turn?

Comment: I am suggesting the third picture is proper usage, which is the first of the two pictures marked up with cyan coloured routes. Your markings don't seem to consider that there are 4 lanes. You can only use lane 1, the bus lane, immediately before the exit. The bus lane breaks there so that traffic can cross it.

Comment: Okay thank you! - I should have included "A" and "B" annotations.    There are only 3 lanes there.

Comment: @WeatherVane Before the intersection: {Turning lane, Straight Lane, Bus lane, Sidewalk}   ---   After the intersection: {Turning lane, Straight lane, Bus lane, Bus Stop}

Comment: In UK, (ignoring the bus lane) when there are two lanes on the exit road, you should only exit from lane 2, if the road markings show it. That is usually when lane 1 is marked 'exit', i.e. no stright ahead option.

Comment: If you include the sidewalk, that's 5 lanes. But it's not a lane. It is clearer [here](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@48.4394365,-123.3675992,3a,75y,176h,82.37t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1srIrVg88KNNjERGqb-guW6w!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?entry=ttu).

Comment: Ah, the map imagery does not match the street view imagery. I'm guessing they added an extra lane in-between taking those two images.

Comment: It's the same as your last image but clearer, and has the same vehicle :)

Comment: Yeah, When I look at the map, it shows three lanes, but you're right when I drive on the road, it's 4. You can see some construction up the road. I bet they were in the process of expanding the road. 
So, are you supposed to enter the bus lane then turn, or turn from the first non-bus lane?

Comment: It doesn't really make any difference whether there is a bus lane. The innermost traffic lane is not required to exit, therefore traffic in the next lane does not have any right of way to exit.

Comment: @WeatherVane Most people using this exit tend to use the bus lane, and pick one or the other lanes on the new road to enter.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the relevant regulation is:

British Columbia Regulation 26/58 [42.02](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/26_58_13/search/CIVIX_DOCUMENT_ROOT_STEM:(bus%20lane)%20AND%20CIVIX_DOCUMENT_ANCESTORS:statreg?2#hit1) (Motor Vehicle Act Regulations: Rules for use of high occupancy lanes)

> (2)A driver of a vehicle that is not a high occupancy vehicle must not
> use a high occupancy vehicle lane except if necessary
>
> (a)to make a right turn from the lane, at the first intersection where
> the turn is permitted, to access a highway intersecting the lane or
> premises adjacent to the lane,
>
> (b)to make a right turn from an intersecting highway or premises
> adjacent to the lane, at the first intersection where the turn is
> permitted, to access the highway in which the lane is situated, or
>
> (c)to merge into an adjacent lane for the purposes of paragraph (b).

It probably needs to be linked to other regulations. I suspect there's one that says you need to turn right from the closest lane unless marked, which I bet this location isn't.

Comment: Thank you! The main question to solve is whether "you need to turn right from the closest lane unless marked".
I'll see if I can find some thing on it.

Comment: You know, I've contacted ICBC (with the same question and diagram)... they told me they're not willing to give me any advice. And I've contacted 7 different city departments (again with the same info) and I've been forwarded to people I've already asked... I've been told to ask the police to enforce traffic there more... like that bloody helps, and I've been told to petition the city planner of some govt. body if I think the intersection is missing signage.

Comment: @CameronCritchlow That's nuts. It might help if you can find accident statistics for the area. That sometimes will prod a government to do something.